# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkState

Tags: selenium-webdriver, rest-assured

I'm trying to automate rest assured API for OAuth 2.0, when i'm trying to implement selenium with rest assured for some purpose[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zjS5N.png), I'm getting this error "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkState(ZLjava/lang/String;0Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;)V"..

Comment: Finally, I found a solution for this. It's simple guys. Add latest guava jar in your project. Note: If you have already old one jar (Please remove that and add it new one). Follow the link : https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.guava/guava/29.0-jre